# Store data in Animation Nodes

Tags: scripting, animation-nodes

I'm working on an Animation Nodes Animation where I create random vectors and different radii to feed a `Close Packing Node`. This is the initial state of my animation and I use the vectors and matrices from the packing node to do my actual animation (the nodes in my screenshots are just for demonstration purposes; I calculate radii and vectors for inital position and scale, close pack, and do sth afterwards, so please ignore that the nodes at the end are useless).

Unfortunately I run into pretty bad performance issues. The close packing node alone takes between 80 and 120ms to calculate and I cannot playback my animation in realtime.

So I would like to split my node tree into multiple, calculate my inital mtrices and vectors only ONCE and then use this data to feed my actual animation (which would run smoothly without the packing).

Is there a way to do that so I dont have to calculate the initial state on every frame?

Omar did something similar here, but my understanding is, that the inital value are calculated but not used.
[Make particles slip around objects in Animation Nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/106679/34533)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Groups have cache options, so you can put expensive nodes inside a group and turn on cache.

[image]

Comment: super cool, didn't know that!!! +1